# Best way to detect that a string passed to $compile in angular is compile-able?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a directive that takes a "message" that can also contain html and nested angular directives. Right now in my directive's contrller I do:

```
var compiled = $compile(message)($scope);
this.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(compiled.html());
```

But it won't compile if the message doesn't have a valid start and end tag. I was wondering if there is another approach or if angular has any way to do this without me using a regex.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? Why not use `try{ } catch`?

Comment: no it doesn't throw an exception, it just does it empty. I am dong this right now:



                    /* First I test if the message has a valid html start and end tag, if not, I do it for them */
                    var hasStartAndEndTag = /^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$/.test(message);
                    if(!hasStartAndEndTag){
                        message = '<span>' + message + '</span>';
                    }
                    var compiled = $compile(message)($scope);
                    this.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(compiled.html());

Comment: What is considered not "compilable". Can you give an example of a `message` that is  not compilable?

Comment: if my message is just  "foo bar bing" it won't work. If its "<span>Foo bar bing </span>" it will its like requiring a template to have a valid start and end tag..

Comment: Why can't you add a root element and compile with it? Then, take the contents out.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely stay away from parsing or validating HTML. jQuery/jqLite already does that for us.

`angular.element` requires a root element. So, wrap your message in the root element, compile and link, then take the contents out:

```
link: function(scope, element){
    scope.param = "test";
    var message = "foo {{param}} bar";

    var el = angular.element("<div>").append(message);
    var compiled = $compile(el)(scope);

    element.append(compiled.contents());
}
```

Comment: I wound up with this because it was faster.


                   /* First I test if the message has a valid html start and end tag, if not, I do it for them */
                    var hasStartAndEndTag = message.charAt(0) === '<' && message.charAt(message.length) === '>';
                    if(!hasStartAndEndTag){
                        message = '<span>' + message + '</span>';
                    }